# onShake method outside of onCreate method

Tags: android, accelerometer, oncreate, sensormanager

My plan is to have a button that initialises the shakelistener when clicked. If the button is not pressed, the shakelistener is not set up.

Currently I have a separate method runShaker() which holds the code to initialise the Shake Listener and the code to be ran when a shake is detected;

```
public void runShaker(){

    //Initialise ShakeDetector
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    //Start Shake Detection
    mShakeDetector = new ShakeDetector();

    mShakeDetector.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeDetector.OnShakeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShake(int count) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Movement Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

However, this code only successfully runs when placed within the onCreate() method. When placed in my runShaker() method nothing currently happens. Any way around this, or something i'm forgetting?

Comment: Did you call `runShaker()` in your `onCreate()` method?

Comment: well do you have a button listener that is in `onCreate` that calls it?

Comment: @shiftpsh Within the onCreate i have an setOnClickListener() method attached to a button. Here i call the runShaker() method.

Comment: @Ivan86 yes, within the onCreate() i have an setOnClickListener() method attached to a button. Here i call the runShaker() method

Comment: So when you click on it nothing happens when runShaker() is outside of onCreate() ?

Comment: @Ivan86 when the button is clicked the runShaker() method is called. However the code within it to start the shake listening does not initialise.

Comment: http://blog.cubeactive.com/onclicklistener-android-tutorial/ try this Private Variable options one of those should work.